# C++ - returning 0

Tags: c++, return

So I'm completely new to C++ but know already a lot about Java.

I'm currently watching thenewboston's tutorial and he said that if you return 0 the computer knows the program works successfully.

Well, my question is now: Does this affect functions? If I want to return a calculated number and it's surprisingly 0, do I get 0 back or does the function send nothing back?

Comment: If one of these answers was useful, please accept it.

Answer (score 8):

> you return 0 the computer knows the program works successfully.

This is specific to the main function. Any other function can return whatever they want. Main is special in that it is the entry point for your program and also the exit point. When your program starts main is called when it only ends once main returns. Watching the return code of the main function is I *think* a practice that is going out of style these days but you still see a lot of code returning things like -1 when an error occurs. Who's watching that error code? The OS most of the time.

Comment: So it doesn't affect normal functions? Hmkay, thank you for the fast answer :D

Comment: @ColdStormy Indeed, it does not affect other functions.

Comment: In general, the semantics of the return value are determined by what the caller does with it.  For functions other than `main`, the author of the function specifies them, and what the caller should expect.  For `main`, there is no "caller", at least within the (C++) program, so the standard specifies what it should be.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes yes, but as you say it depends on the author of the function, a priori there is no such convention for functions other than main because there is no explicit caller.

Comment: Each callee has its own convention. E.g. if `scanf` returns 0, it means an error (zero arguments successfully read).

Comment: @MSalters true, but this is out of the scope of my answer (and in a sense OPs question). His question was "does the convention that main return 0 when all goes well affect/apply to other function" the answer to that is no. Of course other functions have similar conventions but those are chosen by the person who writes those functions or by the standards groups who decide on the interfaces such functions must have, etc

Answer (score 5):

Returning zero is a convention, especially in Unix world. If a program (so it's main() function) returns zero, it means it finished successfully. Other values can (not neccesarily though) mean an error. You can see `sysexits.h` for a list of common return codes.

Also, if you miss return statement, main() will still (implicitly) return zero (valid for C++). It is defined in [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), 3.6.1 point 5:

> If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return
>   statement, the eﬀect is that of executing return 0;

In shell, ex. Bash, you can check what value has been returned from main() by looking at `$?` variable, on example:

```
$ g++ prog.cpp
$ ./a.out
$ echo $?
0
```

For functions other than main() you should remember that zero, in comparison, is a boolean false, so returning zero may not be intepreted as a success (or true). But the return value can be anything and, in general, it does not have any special meaning, so returning zero is okay.

Comment: Declaring `main` with a `void` return type is bad. That one means that if it gets to the ending brace of `main` (still returning `int`), it will implicitly return 0. It makes no guarantees about what will happen if `main` returns `void` (see point 2). By the way, we're up to N3485 now for C++11 and N3690 for C++14. That draft's wording makes is especially clear that `int main` is the only legal one.

Comment: First, it's not just a convention, and it has nothing to do with the Unix world.  The C and the C++ standards both specify clearly that returning `0` (from `main`) is exactly the same as returning `EXIT_SUCCESS`.  Second, the any values other than `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS` or `EXIT_FAILURE` are implementation defined---in particular, Unix only accepts values in the range `[0...255]` (thus, no negative values).  Third, if you declare your `main` as a void function, the compiler is required to reject it.

Comment: @chris The standard _is_ very explicit about what happens if you declare `main` to return `void`.  It requires a diagnostic (and what happens after that is undefined behavior, but from a QoI point of view, it shouldn't compile).

Comment: @JamesKanze, Yeah, I added more at the end. At the time, I was half thinking of C's "or in some other implementation-defined manner" thing. If it makes you happy, I suppose you could pretend I said that it makes no guarantees of what happens should a rogue compiler compile it in the first place (*cough* Borland) :)

Comment: @chris The wording in the C standard was ambiguous.  The "some other implementation-defined manner" still holds, but it doesn't apply to the return value; it allows signatures like `main( int, char**, char** )` (which is supported in Unix, with the third argument providing the environment).

Comment: @JamesKanze, Ah, of all these times looking at it, this was the first time I read it how it's supposed to be read, with the return type offset. Thanks a lot for that.

Comment: @JamesKanze - yes, thanks, I'm glad you've brought that up! Also, I fixed my answer.

Comment: @kamituel And where do you find `sysexits.h`?  It's not standard C.  Nor Unix.  Nor Windows.

Comment: @kamituel I might add, since you mention `bash`, that in Unix shells, the conventions for return codes used as boolean are exactly the opposite as those of C.  It's rare to use `$?`; most of the time, it will be something like `cmd args > tmp && mv tmp arg` or `if cmd args`, in which a return code of `0` from `cmd` is treated as true.

Comment: Finally, I might add that under Windows, `cmd.exe` has similar facilities to those of the shell under Unix.  In particular, the idiom `cmd filename > tmp && mv tmp filename` works.  (This is, of course, the standard idiom for modifying a file in place using a program which outputs the transformation to standard out.)

Answer (score 4):

Returning 0 in the `main` function is the only one that has any special meaning.  It's generally so that the OS can understand the program was successful, it's not particularly interesting insofar as C++ internals itself.